# Como permitir a escolha de um tema no site, através de um arquivo css e memória cache?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tudo bem? Então, estou tentando criar um sistema de escolha individual do tema no meu site, e com isso, necessito que, quando um usuário o escolha, isso fique salvo no cache do navegador, e todas as páginas do site carregem o arquivo css contendo o tema (amarelo.css, azul.css), e sempre que o usuário entrar, o tema escolhido seja aplicado. Já tentei fazer uma gambiarra com um código que guarda um background image, e o exibe sempre que  a página é acessada, e com outro código que faz a página carregar um arquivo css.

```
    if (localStorage.background) 
     document.body.background = localStorage.getItem("background");

    function bac(){
    localStorage.setItem("background", "img/14.png");
    document.body.background = "img/14.png";
    }
```

e

```
  function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {
    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
  }
<a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('positive.css', 0);">STYLE 1</a>
```

Que código devo utilizar? Desde já, grato pela resposta.

Comment: Se for um sistema com BD, você pode solicitar que seja escolhido um tema após o login, e salvar a informação para sempre carregar o tema tal. Em termos de UX fica bem melhor :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode salvar qual tema foi escolhido através do `localStorage`.

`localStorage.setItem('tema', 'branco');`

Para recuperar o valor salvo utilize o método `localStorage.getItem`

`var tema = localStorage.getItem('tema');`

Comment: OK, mas como faço para associar o arquivo CSS ao tema escolhido?